# $location.path('/home') not working with socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I am using express, node, angularJS as my stack, trying to incorporate socket.io emit event from server to client, which I can successfully do, when I angular js controllers do receive a message on the respective channel I am trying to navigate to for example $location.path('/home') but it is not working no error is thrown as well.

### server side emit code:

```
app.get('/api/students/id', asyncMiddleware(async (req, res, next) => {
   const studentData = await getStudent(req.query.studentId);
   io.on('connection', function(socket){
      socket.emit('studentdata', {data: 'payload'});
   });
   res.json(studentData);
}));
```

### client side code:

```
$scope.getStudent = function(){
    var studentData = $scope.Student;
    promise = StudentFactory.get(studentData.id);
    promise.then(function(data){
      var socket = io();
      socket.on('studentdata', function(data){
        if(data){
           console.log('navigating to home.’);
           $location.url('/home’);
        }
  });
  $scope.queriedStudent = data;
  }, function(error){
    console.error('Error - ', error);
    });
};
```

I can see in my browser log 'navigating to home' but nothing happening after that, is it because the channel in which the socket.io is communicating, the same channel is used by $location.path hence cannot navigate? socket.io blocking $location.path

Comment: are you trying with $location.url() or $location.path() ?

Comment: Tried both nothing is happening and no error

Comment: you can also try $state.go('/home')